# Unexpected behavior of data.table := when subsetting

Tags: r, data.table

Given the data.table  `dt <- data.table(a=c(1,NA,3), b = c(4:6))`

```
    a b
1:  1 4
2: NA 5
3:  3 6
```

... , the result for `dt[is.na(a), a := sum(a, na.rm = T)]` is:

```
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 0 5
3: 3 6
```

... , instead of the expected:

```
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 4 5
3: 3 6
```

What is going on? I am using data.table 1.12.8

Comment: You are subsetting on NA values in a. Then summing the NA values. dt[,a:=ifelse(is.na(a),sum(a,na.rm = T),a)][] may bewhat you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `fcoalesce`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, a := fcoalesce(a, sum(a, na.rm = TRUE))]
```